change wordpress log language to something different to website
We are English speaking developers with a website frontend that is in Spanish and the admin panel is in English by changing the langauge for us in our us profiles. - This is all working okay!
The issue lies in what language the logs are in that go into our Apache2 logs. It's all in Spanish!
Is there a way to force the Wordpress Apache2 logs to be English while leaving all other settings the same?

it depends on whether wordpress translation API was used to create the relevant translation. If not, the answer is "no", if yes, the answer is "maybe" and you should probably be more specific about which kind of messages you refer to. My gut feeling is that the answer will be "no" or a "hard to implement yes" but context might make a difference here

Is it just the entries that the WP_Error class logs that are in Spanish, or everything in the Apache logs?

It seems you need to change language on Apache config itself as it dictates which language to use for logging and other stuff.
There seems to be no relation with WordPress language settings as it only translate content for selected language by gettext utility.
So both are different and need to set differently. You can check Apache config, generally named as httpd.conf in Debian family Linux distros.
